# ClassUtil's ClassFinder.concreteSubclasses does not work in tests

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

I am using [ClassUtil](http://software.clapper.org/classutil/) for testing ADT types I created:

```
sealed trait newADT {
  val Id: Int
}

object newADTs {

  val value1 = VALUE1
  val value2 = VALUE2

  def apply(id: Int) = id match {

    case value1.Id => value1
    case value2.Id => value2
  }
}

case object VALUE1 extends newADT {
  override val Id: Int = 1
}
case object VALUE2 extends newADT{
  override val Id: Int = 2
}
```

In my tests (scalatest 3.0.1), I use ClassUtil's `ClassFinder.concreteSubclasses(ancestor: Class[_], classes: Stream[ClassInfo])` to find all the subclasses of my `newADT`. Then, I create an instance from each of the the subclasses and test the apply(id: Int) function on them to see if they were configured correctly.

This way, I don't have to change the tests every time I add a new value.

**THE PROBLEM**:

`ClassFinder.concreteSubclasses` runs wonderfully when executing the tests from within IntelliJ, but when running the test with sbt 0.13.13 (`sbt test`), the `ClassFinder.concreteSubclasses` function returns an empty Iterator.

Comment: https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum